# Not able to run Project giving strange error with Object Mapper

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, objectmapper

I am using `**xcode 7.1**`

I have created simple Model "User" and use 
import ObjectMapper

and xcode showing me following error

**Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11** with following logged error

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/User.swift
cd /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/ViewController.swift /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/AppDelegate.swift -primary-file /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/User.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -I /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo -emit-module-doc-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name ObjectMapperDemo -emit-module-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.swiftdeps -o /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.o

0 swift 0x0000000104a5933b llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE) + 43
1 swift 0x0000000104a59a7b SignalHandler(int) + 379
2 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff84e25f1a _sigtramp + 26
3 swift 0x0000000102d19cd0 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitClassConstructorAllocator(swift::ConstructorDecl) + 1296
4 swift 0x0000000102d2281c swift::SILWitnessVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::SILGenConformance>::visitProtocolDecl(swift::ProtocolDecl) + 940
5 swift 0x0000000102d20035 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::getWitnessTable(swift::ProtocolConformance) + 277
6 swift 0x0000000102d6f890 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1264
7 swift 0x0000000102d6f32e swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl) + 30
8 swift 0x0000000102cf7e0b swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile, unsigned int) + 779
9 swift 0x0000000102cf89c0 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit, llvm::Optional, bool, bool) + 928
10 swift 0x0000000102cf8d6d swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&, llvm::Optional, bool) + 109
11 swift 0x0000000102b4cb92 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef, int&) + 11442
12 swift 0x0000000102b49cd3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char const, void) + 2691
13 swift 0x0000000102b46354 main + 2324
14 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff8dda35c9 start + 1
Stack dump:
0. Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/ViewController.swift /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/AppDelegate.swift -primary-file /Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo/ObjectMapperDemo/User.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -I /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/ObjectMapperDemo-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/jasmin.pethani/Downloads/Demos/iOSDemos/ObjectMapperDemo -emit-module-doc-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name ObjectMapperDemo -emit-module-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.swiftdeps -o /Users/jasmin.pethani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjectMapperDemo-cnzaraylvxjmikeukxijtxxbjvfx/Build/Intermediates/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapperDemo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/User.o
```

i have already raise issue on github
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/363

Comment: Was solved in the linked GitHub issue: add `required init?(_ map: Map){ }`

Comment: Thanks phillee that solved my problem